# Magento 2: Admin user with restricted access can access everything via API?

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3

I have created an admin user to manage my orders and granted the access for order `view` action only. (as below)

But the user can generate token via `API` and access all `order` i.e `view`, `delete`, etc resources.

How to restrict the access to `orders view` only?

[image: ACL Permission assigned to user]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue, it was core Magento bug.

[Admin user with restricted "order create" access can "view", "cancel", etc via API](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/20169)

To fix I need to update the `webapi.xml` in `Sales` module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/orders/:id" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::actions_view" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/orders" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::actions_view" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/orders/:id/statuses" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface" method="getStatus"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::actions_view" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/orders/:id/cancel" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface" method="cancel"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::cancel" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/orders/:id/emails" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface" method="notify"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::emails" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/orders/:id/hold" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface" method="hold"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::hold" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/orders/:id/unhold" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface" method="unHold"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::unhold" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/orders/:id/comments" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface" method="addComment"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::comment" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/orders/:id/comments" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface" method="getCommentsList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::actions_view" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/orders/create" method="PUT">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::create" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/orders/:parent_id" method="PUT">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderAddressRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::create" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/orders/items/:id" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::actions_view" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/orders/items" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::actions_view" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/invoices/:id" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_invoice" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/invoices" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_invoice" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/invoices/:id/comments" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceManagementInterface" method="getCommentsList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_invoice" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/invoices/:id/emails" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceManagementInterface" method="notify"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_invoice" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/invoices/:id/void" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceManagementInterface" method="setVoid"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_invoice" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/invoices/:id/capture" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceManagementInterface" method="setCapture"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_invoice" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/invoices/comments" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceCommentRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_invoice" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/invoices/" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_invoice" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/invoice/:invoiceId/refund" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\RefundInvoiceInterface" method="execute"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_invoice" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/creditmemo/:id/comments" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoManagementInterface" method="getCommentsList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_creditmemo" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/creditmemos" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_creditmemo" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/creditmemo/:id" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_creditmemo" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/creditmemo/:id" method="PUT">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoManagementInterface" method="cancel"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_creditmemo" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/creditmemo/:id/emails" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoManagementInterface" method="notify"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_creditmemo" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/creditmemo/refund" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoManagementInterface" method="refund"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_creditmemo" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/creditmemo/:id/comments" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoCommentRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_creditmemo" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/creditmemo" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales_creditmemo" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/order/:orderId/refund" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\RefundOrderInterface" method="execute"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::creditmemo" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/shipment/:id" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::shipment" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/shipments" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::shipment" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/shipment/:id/comments" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentManagementInterface" method="getCommentsList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::shipment" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/shipment/:id/comments" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentCommentRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::shipment" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/shipment/:id/emails" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentManagementInterface" method="notify"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::shipment" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/shipment/track" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentTrackRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::shipment" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/shipment/track/:id" method="DELETE">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentTrackRepositoryInterface" method="deleteById"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::shipment" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/shipment/" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::shipment" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/shipment/:id/label" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentManagementInterface" method="getLabel"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::shipment" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/order/:orderId/ship" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\ShipOrderInterface" method="execute"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::ship" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/orders/" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::create" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/transactions/:id" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\TransactionRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::transactions_fetch" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/transactions" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\TransactionRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::transactions_fetch" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/order/:orderId/invoice" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceOrderInterface" method="execute"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::invoice" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

The PR is [#20170](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/20170/) and will be merged in 2.3.1 release.